# Python add extra fields to structlog-based formatters within logging

Tags: python, json, logging, stdout, structlog

I'm trying to add the extra fields of my logs as a key-value while keep using standard logging library along with structlog ProcessorFormatter.

Here is an example:

If we use JsonFormatter, extra fields are added as a key-value to the log.

With python-json-logger:

```
formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    handlers=[handler]
)

logger = logging.getLogger('testnameloger1')
logger.debug('testmsg2', extra={'extra2': 2})
```

console:

```
{"message": "testmsg2", "extra2": 2}
```

With rendering using structlog-based formatters within logging:

```
shared_processors = [
    structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
    structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
    structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt='iso'),
]

formatter = structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter(
    processor=structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(),
    foreign_pre_chain=shared_processors,
)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    handlers=[handler]
)

logger = logging.getLogger('testnameloger1')
logger.debug('testmsg1', extra={'extra1': 1})
```

console:

```
{"event": "testmsg1", "logger": "testnameloger1", "level": "debug", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T13:33:50.881221Z"}
```

How can I add the extra fields in the log output ?

Logs I would want would be formatted like:

```
{"event": "testmsg1", "extra1": 1, "logger": "testnameloger1", "level": "debug", "timestamp": "2020-06-16T13:33:50.881221Z"}
```

Thank you for your insight

Answer (score 1):

This works as of structlog 21.5.0!

Check out the [structlog.stdlib.ExtraAdder](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/api.html#structlog.stdlib.ExtraAdder) processor that allows you to pick and choose what to add (adding all if added just as `ExtraAdder()`).

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Add `ExtraAdder()` as a processor to your `pre_chain`. The example at https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html#rendering-using-structlog-based-formatters-within-logging does that.

Comment: The example is quite complex and covers a number of other things as well. Would be helpful if the documentation was broken down into smaller parts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer. Something else might work better.

```
LOG_RECORD_ATTRIBUTES = {
    'args', 'asctime', 'created', 'exc_info', 'exc_text', 'filename',
    'funcName', 'levelname', 'levelno', 'lineno', 'message', 'module',
    'msecs', 'msg', 'name', 'pathname', 'process', 'processName',
    'relativeCreated', 'stack_info', 'thread', 'threadName',
}

def extract_stdlib_extra(logger, method_name, event_dict):
    """
    Extract the `extra` key-values from the standard logger record
    and populate the `event_dict` with them.
    """
    record_extra = {k: v for k, v in vars(event_dict['_record']).items()
                    if k not in LOG_RECORD_ATTRIBUTES}
    event_dict.update(record_extra)
    return event_dict

processors = [
    structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
    structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
    structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt='iso'),
    extract_stdlib_extra,
]

formatter = structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter(
    processor=structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(),
    foreign_pre_chain=processors,
)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    handlers=[handler]
)

logger = logging.getLogger('testnameloger1')
logger.debug('testmsg1', extra={'t': 1, 'z': {'r': 2}, 'k': []})
```

Console:

```
{"event": "testmsg1", "logger": "testnameloger1", "level": "debug", "timestamp": "2020-06-17T08:14:56.465786Z", "t": 1, "z": {"r": 2}, "k": []}
```