# How to add a timestamp and loglevel to each log in Python's structlog?

Tags: python, structlog

How to configure `structlog` so it automatically adds `loglevel` and a `timestamp` (and maybe other fields) by default to each log message it logs? So I do not have to add it to every message explicitly.

I am displaying my messages as JSON (for further processing with Fluentd, Elasticsearch and Kibana). `loglevel` is not (for some reason) included in the output JSON log.

That is how I confiure my `structlog`.

```
structlog.configure(
        processors=[structlog.processors.JSONRenderer()],
        wrapper_class=structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger(logging.INFO),
    )
```

I am logging:

```
log.info("Artist saved", spotify_id=id)
```

Logs I am seeing (mind no `time` and no `loglevel`):

```
{"logger": "get_artists.py", "spotify_id": "4Y6z2aIww27vnxZz9xfG3S",  "event": "Artist saved"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer here: [Python add extra fields to structlog-based formatters within logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62409907/python-add-extra-fields-to-structlog-based-formatters-within-logging)

There are processors that are doing exactly what I needed:

```
structlog.configure(
        processors=[
            structlog.processors.add_log_level,
            structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso", key="ts"),
            structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(),
        ],
        wrapper_class=structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger(logging.INFO),
    )
```

Adding both, `add_log_level` and `TimeStamper` resulted, as expected in the extra fields in the log `..., "level": "info", "ts": "2022-04-17T19:21:56.426093Z"}`.